# CouchDB CORS is not working on a mobile device. Why?

Tags: authentication, mobile, cors, couchdb, pouchdb

My remote CouchDB is running at http://domain:5984/ ...

I've created a simple website to test the sync function of PouchDB...

The website works perfectly on every Computer, but not on any mobile device, in case of an error caused by CORS.

I tried to add the authentication, but it didn't help..

```
        db.logIn('username', 'password').then(function (batman) {
            var db = sessionStorage.getItem("dbName");
            var url = sessionStorage.getItem("url");

            if (db) {
                $('#dbField').val(db);
            }
            if (url) {
                $('#urlField').val(url);
            }

            initPouch();
            initTable();
        });

It works very fine on non mobile devices.. it throws a CORS error just on mobile devices..
```